# resolveUri failing on app private data file

Tags: android, file-io, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm generating a bunch of image files when my app first runs, and then trying to use remoteViews.setImageViewUri() later to get these images into my ImageViews. However, when I run the app I'm seeing

> 01-03 15:05:11.252: W/ImageView(137): Unable to open content:
>   file:///data/data/com.nickavv.cleanwidgets/files/batt_s_19.png 01-03
>   15:05:11.252: W/ImageView(137): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/com.nickavv.cleanwidgets/files/batt_s_19.png (Permission
>   denied)

Since the file was created by this app, I should have permission to access it from within this app, right? Here's the code I'm using to retrieve it:

```
   File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath(), idName+".png");
   Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
   myViews.setImageViewUri(id, newUri);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Uri.parse`, use `Uri.fromfile`.

```
Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Comment: This changed my error into:
`01-03 15:05:11.252: W/ImageView(137): Unable to open content: file:///data/data/com.nickavv.cleanwidgets/files/batt_s_19.png
01-03 15:05:11.252: W/ImageView(137): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.nickavv.cleanwidgets/files/batt_s_19.png (Permission denied)
`

added to the original post for clarity

Comment: That is a permission problem.  The URI is right, but you are not being allowed to access the file.  Is your `RemoteView` in a different process than the one that generated the images?

Comment: the images are generated in the widget's OnEnabled method, and I'm attempting to access them in the OnUpdate method. I was under the impression that I would have access to the private files as long as I was accessing them in the same application

Comment: Within the same app, that is true.  With `RemoteViews` in widgets it might be the the URI is accessed in a different process.  You can try creating your files with [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE).  Note this is deprecated in API 17, and there are some alternatives listed in the description.

Comment: It turns out I'm only using this entire piece of code in API levels 10 and below, so the deprecation shouldn't be an issue. This does seem to have fixed the issue, so thank you!